# Mailcore2: how to receive mail instantly when a new mail arrived?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, apple-push-notifications, mailcore2

I'm building an iOS mail client for receiving mails via mailcore2, with IMAP protocol, I've fetched the mail messages successfully. But, how to implement the remote notification push when the target mail account received a new mail in client? I checked the mailcore2 project and some google search results, no luck there.

Please help, thanks!

**UPDATE**:
Let me clarify the problem details, for the mail client like Airmail in Mac and Microsoft Outlook in iOS, they support to add a IMAP protocol mail account for sending and receiving e-mails, e.g. I added my qq.com mail to Outlook for iOS client, once a new mail arrived to my INBOX in qq mail, I could get an instant remote notification from Outlook client right now.

Let me guess, the mail client didn't upload/save my IMAP-protocol mail config to microsoft/outlook server, all the receiving mail logics just work in local, including communication protocol.

How about IMAP? I've check [this article](http://www.pop2imap.com/) on difference between POP and IMAP. IMAP just keep the client and server have the same account mail data all the time.

Airmail in Mac used mailcore2 in its implementation, so how does it make sure the remote notification work? I don't think they deployed a server side to check the new email arrival for all the user accounts, really.

On mailcore2, I think this is the key point, the remote push should be implemented by it, not some unknown servers. I checked the project structure basically, it's so huge for me and there are many c++ code logics, I must read many mail related blogs before reading it. If someone knows the related guide/wiki/header files, please share to me, or point the mistake on my above guess out, great thanks!

Comment: if you are fetching successfully then is the question just pushing a notification? You will have to implement this in your appdelegate. keep in mind it's different for whether you have the app open or closed when you fetch this information.

Comment: I think google had some APIs in Gmail but otherwise you need a server to implement instant push.

Comment: @BrianDaneshgar , I know the background fetch and app launching delegate usage in iOS, but I need it get an instant remote notification when a new email arrived right now. Thanks!

Comment: @Andy For a mail client, I don't think they really deployed a server to implement instant push for all the user accounts, please check my updates  in question above.

Comment: @Itachi Gmail API has push notifications available – https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push. All other services most likely do not implement this. AFAIK IMAP actually allows you to subscribe for updates but then you need a server for that because your app won't be able to keep it running 24/7.

Comment: @Andy got it, so Airmail did it with full synchronization in server side and push notification to client for supporting 3rd-IMAP mail service?

Comment: @Itachi we can only speculate. You can probably monitor Airmail traffic to see where it sends and receives data from. Most likely they use available Push APIs if possible with fallback to background fetch. Both Exchange and Gmail servers support push notifications. Building own server to monitor IMAP is too much burden and privacy issue too.

Comment: @Andy sorry for that I almost forgot to reply this. It really happened in Airmail client, I found many SSL requests were sent to remote server with port 993 via Proxifier, that is, the mail sync task is handled in background thread in client.